# EF creates a relational id column in the database, which is not part of the model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I have this model:

```
public class Project
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    // some more properties...

    public List<Project> ChildProjects { get; set; }
}
```

In the database, the column "ProjectId" is created, which is used to keep track of the relationship to the parent project.

Since "ProjectId" is not part of the entity model, I can't reference it in my queries.

How can I prevent this column from being created, and use "ParentId" instead?

**UPDATE**

This is my DbContext:

```
public class ProjectsDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ProjectsDbContext(DbContextOptions<ProjectsDbContext> options) : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Check your DB context if you correctly set your relationships.

Comment: @Shocky I added my DbContext to the question. I think it looks to be all right. Isn't it?

Comment: @Shocky `virtual` didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ProjectId` is the EF Core conventional FK property name - `{Entity Name}{Entity PK Property Name}`.

As usual when conventions don't match your model, you have to use explicit configuration with either data annotations or fluent API, for instance in your case

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Project>()
    .HasManye(e => e.ChildProjects)
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.ParentId); // <--
```

For more info, see the [Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key) section of the EF Core documentation.